# Building multiple files matched by globs with a shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, build, gulp, glob

I'm currently using gulp (a nodejs based utility) as my build system which is unnecessarily complex. So wherever I can I have been switching my build system to plain shell scripts. One of the only features I have not found a way to port is matching multiple files with a glob and then building all of them in parallel.

Here is a more specific description of my use case: I want to build sass to css, the glob I use to find the root sass files is this `src/*/index.{sass,scss}`. I then expect my files to be built and output in this directory `dest/*.css` (where `*` represents whatever the glob matched in the initial search).

Is there an easy way to do this with a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaguely, something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in src/*/index.{sass,scss}
do dir=$(dirname "$file")
   subdir=$(basename "$dir")
   dosomecommand with $file to dest/$subdir.css &
done
wait
```

Usually this sort of thing is done with makefiles.